# Submitting a form for use with php inside content loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been search for a solution to this for a while and haven't been able to find one.

My company has quite a few webtools that we use for our jobs and I have been tasked with combining them all into a dashboard page. One of my coworkers started this project but never finished it before he left, so now I have to figure it out and there are quite a few problems.

The dashboard page is composed of a couple of sidebars, plus a "main" element. The sidebar includes a bunch of links that when clicked load specific php pages into the "main" via a call to jQuery AJAX. Here's a simplified example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#pageToLoad").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "some_directory/pageToLoad.php",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#main").html(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#pageToLoad" id="pageToLoad">Load Page</a>
  <main id="main"></main>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is that most of our tools use forms that are submitted via POST and then parsed with PHP (has to be php because it connects to our database to get information needed). Here's a simplified example of a tool page:

```
<?php
  $action = htmlspecialchars($_SRVER["PHP_SELF"]);
  function getResults() {
    if(isset($_POST["infoForQuery"])) {
      //Do some sort of query to database and print out results
    }
  }
?>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="infoForQuery">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  <div>
    <?php getResults();?>
  </div>
</body>
```

I need to be able to use these tools inside the dashboard page, but whenever I try to submit a form, it just reloads the entire dashboard page, resulting in the POST data not existing (maybe this is because the PHP code is run before ajax loads the content into the dashboard page? not sure).

I know I can use AJAX to send the POST like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'some_directory/pageToLoad.php',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        alert('form submitted');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However, this does not allow me to use the data collected in the form to query a database and print results out on the page.

Is it possible to accomplish this without having to leave the dashboard page, and if so, how?

Edit: I believe I've figured it out! What I wasn't realizing was that when I overrode the submit function and used ajax to send the post instead, I could actually retrieve the result of that post and put it into my page. Here's what I did:

```
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_directory/pageToLoad.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $("#main").html(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you to keep your javascript code in one file then include it.

Comment: `but whenever I try to submit a form it just reloads the entire dashboard page` This is not the default behaviour, and I would look for something grabbing the submit event like a generic action trigger `$('form').on('submit' .... ` etc that is interrupting them and modifying the page.  Can you show how the "tools" are loaded, the code that governs the links you mention in the sideboard

Comment: That is what the first code segment shows. When the link with id="pageToLoad" is clicked, the ajax in the script is fired and loads the "some_directory/pageToLoad.php" into the `<main>`

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might cause problems is that when the page is loaded, there is JS that looks at the url of the page and pulls the right page into the `<main>` using the exact same calls that the links use. In the example I gave, if the URL was https://website.com/dashboard/index.php#pageToLoad (which it would be after clicking the link for pageToLoad), it will make the AJAX call and inject pageToLoad into the `main`. However, without this, the dashboard just goes back to the home screen, as submitting the form reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because the submit event is not firing. Since your forms are loaded dynamically do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'some_directory/pageToLoad.php',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        alert('form submitted');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: No, the submit event is firing and it works fine. I was just trying to point out the fact that simply sending the post request to the page doesn't accomplish what I need, as I need to be able to submit the form data to the page that is already loaded via ajax and use that data to show things on the ajax-loaded page.